# VBScript behaves weirdly using SendKeys to send a new line

Tags: shell, vbscript, wsh, sendkeys

I'm working on a very simple VBS script and I've ran into a really weird problem:

I was originally using this code:

```
Set wshShell=wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WScript.Sleep(2000)
Dim i
i = 0
Dim val
val = 25

Do While i < 5
  wshshell.SendKeys("What the")
  WScript.Sleep(val)
  wshshell.SendKeys("{ENTER}")
  WScript.Sleep(val)
  i = i + 1
Loop
```

But for some reason, the output was this:

```
What theWhat theWhat theWhat theWhat the
```

But when I change this:

```
wshshell.SendKeys("What the")
```

To this:

```
wshshell.SendKeys("What the ")
```

It works fine and outputs:

```
What the 
What the 
What the 
What the 
What the
```

What's causing that? I'm extremely baffled as to why that happens. Thanks.

Comment: Tried your script and it outputs fine on new lines without the space being added, maybe it's a slow machine, try increasing the delay from `25` to `100`ms and see if that helps.